# Windows properly detect active window changed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events, hook

I write a DLL need to know current active window and detect when active window changed.

For detecting active window changed, I use SetWinEventHook and listen for the EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND event.

```
hEvent = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND , NULL, WinEventProcCallback,0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
```

I've found that this doesn't work consistently. Sometimes my callback is called, other times not, depending from what to what focus is switched. Perhaps another event...

Is there any Windows (WINAPI?) event which fires every time the active (focused) window changed? I'd like to subscribe with my callback function.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the events you're missing are when the target is a window of an elevated process? I wouldn't be surprised if it skips giving you events for processes elevated above yours.